# "switch something to something" or "switch something for something"?

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please which preposition I have to use in the following context, *to* or *for*:

> 1. If you come home and realize that the jeans you bought doesn't really fit you, then you can easily take them back to the shop and switch **to** other ones fitting.
> 2. If you come home and realize that the jeans you bought doesn't really fit you, then you can easily take them back to the shop and switch **for** other ones fitting.

Comment: In these examples, "doesn't" should be changed to "don't".

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine, although they might have very slightly different nuances. I think of switching *to* something as having more emphasis on throwing out or not using the original thing anymore, while switching *for* has more of an emphasis on the transaction. Functionally, though, they're interchangeable (though you might need slightly different wording based on the context), and I'd probably say something like this:

> If you **go** home and realize that the jeans you bought **don't fit**, then you can easily take them back to the shop and **switch them out for ones that fit better**.

You could also say "switch *to* ones that fit better".